# Image manipulation webservice ("image manipulation as-a-Service")

Tags: image-processing, apex-code, force.com

I'm developing on the force.com platform (Apex code) and need to do some basic image manipulation (cropping and scaling). The platform does not ([yet?](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&id=08730000000BrdBAAS)) support image manipulation.

Therefore I think I am looking a "image manipulator as-a-service". Basically a hosted webservice that takes my image along with manipulation instructions and return a manipulated image.

Any recommendations for a reliable service that does this. Alternatively suggestions to different approaches to the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only candidates I've been able to find are these:

- http://www.appspotimage.com/
- http://dsin.appspot.com/image

Both would probably require a serious evaluation before being used for production purposes, so my conclusion is that no good answer currently exists for this answer.

Setting up a the service for yourself or waiting for the [IdeaExchange idea](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&id=08730000000BrdBAAS) to become real are unfortunately well worth considering.